# What is this advertisement on the bottom-left of a YouTube video?

Tags: video, youtube

[image: Advert in lower left corner]

YouTube has now disabled the creation of Annotations, and instead has given us "[End Screens](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6388789?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)" and "[Cards](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6140493?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en-GB)", but I can't see how to recreate this particular look with either.

**Is this an advertisement? If so, what type?** It doesn't seem to appear in their [advertising documentation](https://support.google.com/displayspecs/answer/187095?hl=en), either (which states that overlay advertisements are 480x70).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [call to action overlay](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/150471?hl=en) (which is different from an overlay ad). CTA overlays are available in advertisements (if a video ever has been used as a video ad, any CTA overlays that have been inserted during the campaing remain on it afterwards), for non-profit accounts and for [twitch live notifications](https://blog.twitch.tv/twitch-live-annotations-for-youtube-fb00818c1ad2).

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like an affiliate link, an easy way to buy the product whilst giving the creator a small kickback, I may be wrong. To recreate it I think you need AdSense, even though it's not **technically** an ad.